# Dagger for Android - cant define injection for class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, butterknife

I cant seem to use the injects word when trying to define classes that will use my injections.

Here is my MainModule.java class:

```
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;


@Module()
public class MainModule {

    private Context context;

    public MainModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Provides
    Object provideSomething(Context context) {
        return new Object();
    }
}



@Module()
 class SubModule1 {

    private Context context;

    public SubModule1(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    Object provideSomethingElse(Context context) {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Here is my MainApplication class that extends application in android:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MainModule(this));
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new SubModule1(this));
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ActivityModule());
        objectGraph.inject(this);
}
    }
```

And here is the issue im having below, android studio wont see the injects keyword so i cant use it.

The ActivityModule.java class is below:

```
@Module(
        injects=
                ListPageActivity.class

) 
public class ActivityModule { }
```

Again its the injects keyword in ActiveModule that is not recognized in my IDE. Here is my gradle build dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:dagger:0.9.1'

}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using 0.9.1 instead of the latest?

Comment: I thought that was the latest I checked on J center and maven central. could you give me the latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your version of dagger.  Everything seems to be OK for me with the posted code.

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
```

The group id changed so know you can find the project on maven central [here](http://search.maven.org/#browse|1510145097)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use 0.9.1 version, use `entryPoints` keyword instead. That's because `injects` is renamed `entryPoints` and exists in newer versions.

I recommend you to use the last, 1.2.2 version from Square which have `injects`:
http://square.github.io/dagger/

```
apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2"
compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2"
```

Or the newest Dagger 2 from Google. It's still snapshot but I hope not for long.:
http://google.github.io/dagger/.

```
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Comment: hey thanks - plus one. Can you give me the gradle dependency to compile in android studio. I cant find it. I am referring to the dagger 2 from google package.

Comment: You have maven dependency on project website. It's easy to transform it to Gradle but I've edited the answer.

Comment: Error: "Gradle DSL method not found: apt()"

Comment: You need to use android-apt plugin in your project: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt